# How to create one docker container per web service request?

Tags: web-services, docker

I have a quite heavy batch process (a python script called "`run_simulation.py`") on which I have very little control, it can be launched by a single user through a web api but it read and writes from disk so it wouldn't handle parallel requests.

Now, I'd like to have one docker container instanciated per request so that all requests can be handled in parallel, what would be the way to do this ? Is this even doable with Docker ? What would be the module responsible to instanciate the container and pass the http request to it ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don’t do this.  There are two good reasons for that: if you unconditionally launch a container per request it becomes very easy to swamp your system with these background jobs to the point where none can progress; and the setup that would allow you to launch more Docker containers would also give you unlimited root-level access to the host, which you don’t want in a process that accepts network requests.

A better approach is to set up a job queue system.  [RabbitMQ](https://rabbitmq.com/) is popular and open-source, but by no means the only option.  When you receive a request that needs background work, you add a job to the queue and return immediately.  Meanwhile, you have some number of worker processes which accept jobs from the queue and do the work.

This gives you a couple of benefits.  You control how much work can be done in parallel (by controlling the number of worker containers).  If you need to do more work by setting up a second server (or even more), they can all connect back to the same queue server, without requiring a complex multi-host container setup.  If your workers crash (or get OOM-killed) their jobs will be returned to the queue and can be picked up and retried by other workers.  If you decide Docker doesn’t work for you, or that you need a different orchestrator (Nomad, Kubernetes) you can run this exact same setup without making any code changes, just changing the deployment configuration.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this advice. Can you precise the most natural protocol to do what I try to do with a message broker ? Because I know mostly MQTT and it's a publish-subscribe protocol, quite different from the synchronous call I'm doing now.

Comment: MQTT is a little different; I know there are a couple of commercial products from different vendors with “MQ” in their names that would be appropriate here too.  AMQP is the common protocol but different versions of it are quite different, and the AMQP-0-9 that RabbitMQ speaks is different from the AMQP-1-0 that the commercial products use.

Comment: Well Rabbit MQ do support AMQP 1.0 and MQTT via plugins, but my question was not about a specific taste of protocol but more about HTTP vs MQxx. How do you receive a HTTP response when u've put your HTTP request in a message queue ?

Comment: Receive the HTTP request, put the message on the queue requesting the async job, immediately return an HTTP response.  If you're feeling more advanced you can create a URL to check on the job status and return that in a 201 Created response.

Comment: Ok, but I don't want to return a "ok your sim is started" response I want to return the result of the simulation (let's say it's a binary file). I dont understand where do I put this result so it can be seen by the requester and only him of course. Isnt it a classic need ?

Comment: I guess the answer is : the backend has to post his response to a "reply channel" and the requester has to subscribe to this reply channel to get a reponse. Much more complicated than a syncronous call, I rly hoped there were some simple way to do this.

Comment: If your job takes long enough that you need to spin up a separate process to run it, it probably takes too long to return it in a synchronous HTTP response.  (If it ever takes >30 seconds you will hit problems with timeouts at various layers.)

Answer (score 0):

Use AWS lambda service, it will run each request into a separate container, all the heavy lefting is done for you.